# Matching string between first and last quote

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that contains a JSON object. Problem is the object is being returned like this for some reason:

```
string (4345) "{ "blabla" : { "bleble" : "bloblo" } ...}"
```

I need to extract everything between the first and last quotation basicly so that I can then decode the object.

I tried this in javascript:

```
var myVar = myString.match(/\".+$\"/);
```

But it's not working. What's the appropriate RegEx for my problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you look into why it is returning such a string instead of coding a hack?

Comment: Can't change it, it's coming from a third party web service.

Comment: @ReX357 - I would  reconsider using such a service.

Comment: How did you get that output? Are you sure that the outermost `"`s are part of the string itself, rather than simply part of your debug tool's mechanism of presenting strings?

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Not an option, have to use it.

Comment: @ReX357 - Everyone always says that.

Comment: does it contain the elipsis as well? or do you simply want `/"(.*)"/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you know that (in your example) myString has your JSONed thing?  Why not do:

```
   var myVar = myString.substring(1, myString.length - 2);
```

If there's some other junk before or after your JSONed thing, I guess you could use the indexOf and lastIndexOf operations.

Also check out this question:
[Regex to validate JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json)

In response to the question in the comment:

```
//So let's say we have this string
example = '"[ { "title": "event1", "start": "NOW", } ]"'
//So our example string has quote literals around the bits we want

//indexOf gives us the index of the " itself, so we should add one
//to get the character immediately after the "
first_nonquote_character = example.indexOf('"') + 1 

//lastIndexOf is fine as is, since substring doesn't include the character
//at the ending index
last_nonquote_character = example.lastIndexOf('"')

//So we can use the substring method of the string object and the
//indices we created to get what we want

string_we_want = example.substring(first_nonquote_character, last_nonquote_character)

//The value in string_we_want is
//[ { "title": "event1", "start": "NOW", } ]
```

Hope that helps. BTW if your JSON is actually coming back with the ', } ]"' at the end of it and that's not a typo, you'd probably want to do a string.replace(/, } ]"$/, '}]').

Comment: Good idea on indexOf and lastIndexOf. Worked like a charm. Sometimes I just complicate things for nothing.

Comment: Do you mind pasting an example of how you used indexOf and lastIndexOf up the double quotes before and after the json. I am getting "[
    {
        "title": "event1",
        "start": "NOW",
        
    }
]" when using JSN.stringify and I want to remove the quotes surrounding the json. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get the group submatch:

```
/"(.*)"/.exec(myString)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex worked for me (I tested it with [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/2nButSofmJ)):

```
/"(.+)"/
```

And you could use it like this:

```
var newString = oldString.replace(/"(.+)"/, "$1");
```

Where the parens are for capturing what's in between the quotation marks (because you didn't want them, right?).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var newstr = oldstr.match(/"(.+)"/)[1];
```