# Using Python to extract JSON from a .js file also containing non-JSON declarations?

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have inherited a number of javascript files containing a mixture of JSON objects and other js declarations (functions, variables).  I'm writing a python script to move the data contained in the JSON objects into another system.

I'd like to avoid duplicating any sort of parser functionality in what is essentially a throw away script and avoid combing through the files by hand.

Is there a nice (pythonic) solution to filter out the JSON in these files and pass it to json.loads() ?

Comment: Why not use some kind of javascript engine, possibly with a python bridge, to access the new objects created (which are just "plain") objects, then output those as json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to isolate those JSON objects you are interested in from your available files. Here is [a relevant discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json)

Answer (score 0):

If the data just contained json then probably, but if it contains other javascript declarations then it won't be considered well-formed json

Comment: Right.  I'm looking for a nice way filter out only the JSON.

Comment: @John Carter I never used phython, but I never heard of a way in any language to extract json among other javascript declarations