# How to extract JSON from an unruled text using Java

Tags: java, json, extract

Here is a link that tells us how to extract json from a text!
[Extract JSON from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574520/extract-json-from-text)

But I need it use Java with high performance, and I really don't want use the three-part plugin to help with.

Who can help me? it got me crazy. Thank you all.

Comment: have you looked at Jackson: http://jackson.codehaus.org/ ?  also search for GSON. lots of java libs for this depending on your needs

Comment: Parsing JSON is easy, and is not inefficient (other than the cost of creating the resulting objects).  What precisely is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really have a performance problem?  Hard to know if you haven't measured it.  And that's hard to do if you haven't written any code yet.  Look you aren't going to write a super fast JSON parser that no one else hasn't already done for you.  You're roughly going to have to do the same amount of work that anyone who created a 3rd party plugin has already done.  Stop worrying about performance and go get a library to do this for you.  There are plenty out there.  Plain vanilla JSONObject fits the bill.

http://json.org

Personally I like http://flexjson.sourceforget.net it has descent performance and good feature set.

Comment: OK, thanks for your response, I will try some 3rd party plugins and find the best solution. I think I must extract it out firstly and then consider about performance.