# Reach JSON object by ignoring what comes before

Tags: json, node.js

Allright, this is what I have in a variable.

```
[SXWE] Nickname : test
{
  "Message": "test",
  "UserId": 50,
  "Username": "Nickname"
}
```

I want to check if this json object exists by using hasOwnproperty.
The issue here is that I have something before the object itself and it seems like it does not find the key of the Object because it is getting blocked at the first line

Comment: If your json always starts from the second lien, just skip the first line.

Comment: Yeah, it never gets into the same line. I assume it is always starting from a new line. But the first line might not always be only one line. It could be a total of two lines at the beginning

Comment: Perhaps , you should extract JSON from you text then parse it , you will find an answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10574546/5244459