# How to prompt chatGPT API to give completely machine-readable responses, without superfluous commentary?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm trying to write prompts for chatGPT API. I want it to respond with purely machine readable JSON responses containing information I want.

I want it to appraise a description of a project, and in JSON, specify properties of that appraisal, such as "estimated_hours_of_work". I don't want it to give any text outside of what is requested in JSON format, so my code can evaluate and use the response.

How can I do that? I can't seem to engineer a prompt where the response is purely JSON, it always seems to give extra commentary such as:

> Certainly! Here's the appraisal of the text you provided in pure JSON
> format, without any additional comments or text:

I either want to use gpt-3.5-turbo or gpt-4

Comment: Hi. There's a lot more interaction about prompts on reddit (try the OpenAI subreddit). I've seen many dozens of prompts and remember seeing examples similar to what you're requesting. From what I gather, it's a bit of an art at this point. You may get the results you need, and find it doesn't work a few days later.

Answer (score 6):

My experiments with JSON output suggest that response can't blindly be trusted as there is always some "befores" and "afters" (with higher temperatures even more so). On the other hand JSON is always there somewhere in the response text.

**Solution:**

1. Ask for JSON, but give a tiny example `{ colors: ["string"] }`
2. Use extractor function that finds `{ ... }` see [Extract JSON from text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10574546/11256058)
3. Return `result.colors`

**Prompt:**

```
Generate 5 colors depending on users mood.

Return results in JSON format like this: { colors: ["string"] }
```

**Users input:**

```
Happy
```

**Response:**

```
Here are some colors!

{ "colors": ["#FAD02E", "#53A647", "#00BCD4", "#FFC107", "#76FF03"] }
```

**JSON extracted using extractor function:**

```
{ "colors": ["#FAD02E", "#53A647", "#00BCD4", "#FFC107", "#76FF03"] }
```

**Final result:**

```
["#FAD02E", "#53A647", "#00BCD4", "#FFC107", "#76FF03"]
```

--

If prompts are complex double-prompting might be required since for content generation requires high temperatures, but valid JSON requires low temperature.

Comment: Isn't this what ChatGPT "functions" were created for? https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/function-calling

Comment: Functions are something different, but there is a new method for output formatting https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/json-mode

Answer (score 1):

Per the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76185628/how-to-prompt-chatgpt-api-to-give-completely-machine-readable-responses-without#comment136328029_76751441) by `Velocedge`, this can be achieved using GPT Function calling: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/function-calling

Basically, you tell GPT that there's a method whose parameters conform to the schema of the JSON you want to get (of course, such a method doesn't actually have to exist). Here's a (python) template for [what we did](https://github.com/4tals/LinksForIsrael/pull/332):

```py
import logging
import openai

messages = [
    {
        "role": "system", 
        "content": "You are only used for function calling, and must exclusively use the function you have been provided with"
    },
    {
        "role": "user", 
        "content": "Please provide arguments for the foo method using the following guidelines: ..."
    }
]

# there "params" are actually the JSON schema you want GPT to return
foo_params = {
    "displayName": { 
        "type": "string", 
        "description": "The text displayed for foo" 
    },
    "tags": { 
        "type": "array", 
        "items": { "type": "string" },
        "description": "some tags to find foo easily"
    },
    "category": { 
        "type": "string",   
        "enum": [ "important", "not important" ],
        "description": "category in which foo resides"
    },
}

functions = [
{
    "name": "foo",
    "description": "do something",
    "parameters": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": foo_params
    },
}]

response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model = 'gpt-4',
    messages = messages,
    functions = functions,
    function_call = {"name": "foo"}
)

response_choice = response["choices"][0]

finish_reason = response_choice["finish_reason"]
if finish_reason != "stop" and finish_reason != "function_call":
    logging.warn("GPT responded with unexpected finish reason: " +  finish_reason)

response_message = response_choice["message"]
if "function_call" in response_message:
    logging.info("GPT decided to call a function as expected, returned arguments: {0}".format(response_message["function_call"]["arguments"]))
else:
    logging.warn("GPT did not infer function calling, returned generic answer: {0}}".format(response_message["content"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think JUBEIs answer on how to generate machine-readable responses in JSON is already very good and complete. Just another hint regarding your ChatCompletion instantiation: set the temperature to 0. The temperature is a parameter between 0 and 2 introducing random noise in the model interference process, and with reducing the noise, you increase the proability to retrieve an answer in valid JSON format (remember that the model interference is a non-deterministic process). So in your initial example code, it will look like the following:

```
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model = 'gpt-4',
    temperature = 0,
    messages = messages,
    functions = functions,
    function_call = {"name": "foo"}
)
```