# updating multiple properties in Cypher (neo4j)

Tags: neo4j

I cannot update the node using SET for multiple properties in Neo4j, is there any way to handle this?

```
start n=node:wordindex(word='repine') set     n.wordType = 'rare'         return n
```

If I want to add n.link = "..." how is that done?

Answer (score 13):

Here is the newest doc: http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/set/

```
 MATCH (n { name: 'Peter' })
 SET n += { hungry: TRUE , position: 'Entrepreneur' }
```

There are other ways also, so check the docs.

Also check this out if you are doing this from **node.js**: [JSON.Stringify without quotes on properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233498/json-stringify-without-quotes-on-properties)

You can use `util.inspect()` to get an object in like this:

```
 const util = require('util')

 const params = {
   hungry: TRUE ,
   position: 'Entrepreneur'
 }

 const query = `
   MATCH (n { name: 'Peter' })
   SET n += ${util.inspect(params)}
   RETURN n
 `
```

Answer (score 9):

```
start n=node:wordindex(word='repine')
set n.wordType = 'rare', n.link='link'
return n
```

should do it

Comment: I will try it. I had tried that and it failed. But I will try again.

Comment: The docs: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-set.html#set-set-multiple-properties-using-one-set-clause

Answer (score 2):

I have an example which i have tried and worked!

Below is the cypher query created the node:

```
CREATE (n:myAsset {name: 'Test CBP2', Description: 'my test Description', GUID: 'ID000002', Subtype: 'cat-a-cb', Notes: 'my_Notes'  })
```

I have updated multiple properties by using SET:

```
MATCH (n:myAsset {GUID: 'ID000002'}) SET n.Description='Updated description',n.Subtype='cat-b-cb', n.Notes='New Notes added' RETURN n
```