# How to convert JSON object to a different format

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, neo4j

I have a JSON object like this

```
{
    "name": "Test Name",
    "age": 24
}
```

Is there a way I can convert this to a **String** in a format like

```
{
    name: "Test Name",
    age: 24
}
```

The JSON will be of varying lengths with different properties.

Right now, I am doing this as shown below. This can get too long and messy for larger and more complex JSON objects. I need to know if there is an easier and cleaner solution for this.

```
let cypherQueryObject = '{';
cypherQueryObject += ` name: "${user.name}";
if (user.age) { cypherQueryObject += `, age: "${user.age}"` };
cypherQueryObject = '}';
```

Comment: Basically, you want to remove the quotes wrapping the keys?

Comment: Can probably do as a string operation with Regex (see [JSON regex from other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845829/2064544))

Comment: @31piy Yeah. Basically.

Comment: This is a vague requirement. Why do you want to do this? AFAIK, there is no _easier and cleaner_ solution for this, unless you convert the JSON to string, and do a RegExp replace everywhere, but that isn't fullproof either.

Comment: @31piy I am guessing this should have been part of the post as well. I am writing a Cypher query for Neo4j GraphDB. To add node properties this is the format that is required as part of the query.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen The code here is an attempt to provide an example of how I am dealing with it right now. In my real code, most things like this have been taken care of, like booleans, numbers, other JSON or arrays.

Comment: Parse with an AST parser and then re-assemble with a grammar slightly different from real JSON. [Popular parser](https://github.com/rse/json-asty)

Comment: Either use @TobiasMühl's suggestion, or write your own logic to recursively visit and stringify all properties/elements of the object/array.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion with my answer, clearly I didn't read the question deeply enough. After some quick googling, I believe it's a possible duplicate of [JSON.stringify without quotes on properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233498/json-stringify-without-quotes-on-properties)

Comment: @JBallin Good find.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that you are looking for is little different than what someone expect. JavaScript's `JSON.stringify()` generates `JSON` string and a valid `JSON` contains `"` (double quotes only) around keys.

> In your case, you are trying to use the JSON string without `"` around keys. So here is a little simple process to do that. Here I am assuming that you are going to use this in simple kind of `JSON` strings where the value part of any key don't have `key:` kind of things then it will work fine of bigger `JSONs` too.
>
> If it is not like that then you will need to improve the find & replace utility in more efficient form. Regular expressions are great for this work.

Here I have tried to solve your problem like this.

> I have used **NODE REPL** to execute statements so please ignore `undefined` returned by default.

```
> 
> let o = {
...     "name": "Test Name",
...     "age": 24
... }
undefined
> 
> s = JSON.stringify(o)
'{"name":"Test Name","age":24}'
> 
> s = JSON.stringify(o, undefined, 4)
'{\n    "name": "Test Name",\n    "age": 24\n}'
> 
> console.log(s)
{
    "name": "Test Name",
    "age": 24
}
undefined
> 
> for(k in o) {
... s = s.replace("\"" + k + "\":", k + ':')
... }
'{\n    name: "Test Name",\n    age: 24\n}'
> 
> console.log(s)
{
    name: "Test Name",
    age: 24
}
undefined
>
```

you can have a look at this as well.

[image]

Comment: Sadly only works when used with objects as simple as the example. For example, this will fail if key or value include a `"` or if there are nested objects.

Comment: Also note that some input JSON might have quotes around the `24` integer value

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I have already mentioned that if @Ajil has any complex JSON then he/she will need to improve the code's find & replace utility. I just presented based on current i/p provided. Thank you.