# Convert Object to string in javascript without the quotes in key

Tags: javascript

How can I convert an Object to a string so that output is something like this:

e.g. `let a = {b: "c"}`

Let's assume the above example is our sample Object. Now we can use `JSON.stringify(a)` to convert it to string but that outputs,

`console.log(a)` -> `{"b": "c"}` but I want something like this: `{b: "c"}` in the original Object format.

Comment: when in doubt for loop out

Comment: Why do you want the original not valid JSON format?

Comment: @mplungjan I need to pass this object as part of graphql query. Issue is I can only pass it like this: (a: "b", c: "d"). It throws error if string is like this: ("a": "b", "c":"d")

Comment: That is unfortunate. Perhaps fix or ask to have the graphql code fixed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233498/json-stringify-without-quotes-on-properties/11233515

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233498/json-stringify-without-quotes-on-properties).

There is a regex solution that is simpler but it has a shortcoming that is inherent to regex. For some edge cases in complex and nested objects it does not work.

```js
const data = {a: "b", "b": "c",
              c: {a: "b", "c": "d"}}

console.log(stringify(data))

function stringify(obj_from_json){
    if(typeof obj_from_json !== "object" || Array.isArray(obj_from_json)){
        // not an object, stringify using native function
        return JSON.stringify(obj_from_json);
    }
    // Implements recursive object serialization according to JSON spec
    // but without quotes around the keys.
    let props = Object
        .keys(obj_from_json)
        .map(key => `${key}:${stringify(obj_from_json[key])}`)
        .join(",");
    return `{${props}}`;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try using a Reg-ex, where you replace only the first occurrence of `""` with white space character using `$1` in the [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) call:

```js
const a = JSON.stringify({a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}).replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:');
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [javascript-stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-stringify) npm package.