# How to insert array of objects into a string that gets written to file

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[ { color: 'red',
    direction: { width: 1, height: 3 },
    alpha: 0.5,
    blur: 3 },
  { color: 'green',
    direction: { width: 1, height: 9 },
    alpha: 0.09,
    blur: 11 } ]
```

I need to insert it into a string that looks like this:

```
'exports.' + name + ' = ' + ARRAY_ABOVE_HERE + ';'
```

So that the final outcome — what gets written to a file — is this:

```
exports.shadow = [
  {
    color: 'red',
    direction: { width: 1, height: 3 },
    alpha: 0.5,
    blur: 3
  },
  {
    color: 'green',
    direction: { width: 1, height: 9 },
    alpha: 0.09,
    blur: 11
  }
];
```

What happens currently is the [object Object] deal (`exports.shadow = [object Object],[object Object];`). I thought `JSON.parse()` might be what I'm looking for but no luck there.

Is there some utility or pattern I'm missing that does this? Or do I need to just reconstruct it by mapping the array and manually concatenating the properties with the values?

Comment: So you've found `JSON.parse()` but not `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(ARRAY_ABOVE_HERE)` should do it

Comment: That's what I was using initially but I didn't like that it put double quotes around the object properties.

Comment: Thanks all, I think this is probably what I'm looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233498/json-stringify-without-quotes-on-properties

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it using [`JSON.stringify( object, null, '\t' )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_space_argument) as seen in this sample

```js
const content = [ { color: 'red',
    direction: { width: 1, height: 3 },
    alpha: 0.5,
    blur: 3 },
  { color: 'green',
    direction: { width: 1, height: 9 },
    alpha: 0.09,
    blur: 11 } ];
    
console.log( 'exports.shadow = ' + JSON.stringify( content, null, '\t' ) + ';');
```