# How to generate minimum-size Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, minify, object-literal

How can I create a minimum-sized Javascript serialization of a Javascript object? Essentially a `JSON.stringify` with all unnecessary quotes removed. (Only basic JSON data types need to be supported, not Dates etc.)

For example, the JSON:

```
{
  "pi": 3.14,
  "e!": 4.26
}
```

would become:

```
{pi:3.14,"e!":4.26}
```

Edit: The result is *not* valid JSON, but *is* valid Javascript.

Comment: This is not a proper JSON, since the quotes are *mandatory*.

Comment: `all unnecessary quotes` The spec says those quotes are very necessary.  You are producing invalid JSON.

Comment: I am not producing JSON, I am producing Javascript.

Comment: But you said JSON?

Comment: run it through a minifier?

Comment: Write you own `stringify` method using `Object.entries(obj)`. Still, this sounds like an XY problem, so why do you need this? And you should add your own attempt to the question.

Comment: The confusion on my end was caused by `a minimum-sized Javascript serialization`.  Serialized JS is referred to as JSON.  If you want to produce JS *code*, I'd amend that line accordingly.

Comment: use a js minifier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.stringify without quotes on properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233498/json-stringify-without-quotes-on-properties)

Comment: @TahaPaksu not a (complete) dupe. It only covers removing quotes from keys but doesn't minimise the space needed, nor does it (necessarily) check if the unquoted key is syntactically correct.

Comment: Yea you are right, but the answers given there with a slight modification leads to the answer. Modifying the regexes there to exclude non-alphanumeric characters, and removing the spaces between keys and values should be enough. Well, I might give an answer..

Comment: I'm still not sure why OP doesn't want to use a minifier.

Comment: `.replace(/"(\w+)":/g,"$1:")` will kill quotes on valid keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11233515/916000 and modified:

```js
function stringify(obj_from_json) {
  if (typeof obj_from_json !== "object") {
    return JSON.stringify(obj_from_json);
  } else {
    if (Array.isArray(obj_from_json)) {
      // if the array contains an object
      var arr = [];
      for (var i = 0, len = obj_from_json.length; i < len; i++) {
        arr.push(stringify(obj_from_json[i]));
      }
      return "[" + arr.join(",") + "]";
    } else {
      var props = Object
        .keys(obj_from_json)
        .map(function(key) {
          return (new RegExp(/^[1-9a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$.]*$/).test(key) ? key : "\"" + key + "\"") + ":" + stringify(obj_from_json[key]);
        }).join(",");
      return "{" + props + "}";
    }
  }
}


console.log(stringify({
  "pi": 3.14,
  "e!": 4.26
}));

console.log(stringify([{
  "adjacencies": [{
    "nodeTo": "graphnode2",
    "nodeFrom": "graphnode1",
    "data": {
      "$color": "#557EAA"
    }
  }],
  "data": {
    "$color": "#EBB056",
    "$type": "triangle",
    "$dim": 9
  },
  "id": "graphnode1",
  "name": "graphnode1"
}, {
  "adjacencies": [],
  "data": {
    "$color": "#EBB056",
    "$type": "triangle",
    "$dim": 9
  },
  "id": "graphnode2",
  "name": "graphnode2"
}]));

console.log(stringify({1: 2}));
console.log(stringify({"000": 42}));
console.log(stringify({1.26: 42}));
```

**Edit**: Added object array support.
**Edit**: Fixed array conversion.

Comment: Now try it with `{1: 2}` or `{"1": 2}`

Comment: If they are valid objects, yes I will.

Comment: The expected result is `{1:2}`, your code produces `{"1":2}`. After you fix it - it would be possible to find another edge case. And so on, and so forth.

Comment: @zerkms, yes, added three more characters.

Comment: Now try `{"000": 42}`, the expected result is `{"000":42}`

Comment: :D let me ask, why not `{000:42}` ?

Comment: Because `{000:42}` is identical to `{"0":42}`, `000` numeric literal is collapsed to `0` then stringified. `const o = {000: 42}; console.log(o["0"]);`

Comment: Yea, I was expecting that. Do we need to create the perfect regex for this question? I can continue.

Comment: "Do we need to create the perfect regex for this question? I can continue." --- So can I. My point here is that one could take a parser instead of making up a regex that would always fail to cover some cases.

Comment: Yes, waiting for another edge case Ivan.

Comment: Easy: `{1.42: 42}`

Comment: is this even valid?

Comment: Why wouldn't it

Comment: Are floats allowed as an object key? Let me check that. Very interesting.

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-object-initializer

Comment: Cool, now let's switch to unicode `{aॏ: 42}` (but there are cases even with numbers still)

Comment: :D all property types are strings, yes. Will you write anything that you can convert to a string? One could take a parser instead of a regex, that would fail too?

Comment: ":D all property types are strings, yes" --- not all of them should be enclosed in strings. `aॏ` should not. "that would fail too?" --- if it's standard compliant - nope, it'd be okay.