# Remove double quotes from object properties unless start with number

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I've googled and gone through stack overflow Q&A's but haven't found this exact scenario. I have an object like so:

```js
props: {
  "label": "1rem",
  "text3": "1rem",
  "text2Button": "1rem",
  "1": "1rem",
  "5spacing": 2
}
```

I am using this regex pattern to capture the object property names and remove the double quotes based on a [simplified version of another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233498/json-stringify-without-quotes-on-properties#comment85036380_11233515):

```
/"([^"]+)":/g
```

This worked great, but I wanted the numbers to keep their double quotes, so I changed it to this:

```
/"([^"0-9]+)":/g
```

However, this only matches `"label"` and any property with a number is excluded. I understand why this is happening, what I can't figure out is how do I match properties that have a number in them but exclude those that *begin* with a number.

The desired regex pattern would match `"label"`, `"text3"`, and `"text2Button"` only so that I could then transform the object to this:

```js
props: {
  label: "1rem",
  text3: "1rem",
  text2Button: "1rem",
  "1": "1rem",
  "5spacing": 2
}
```

(I couldn't figure out how to do combine the exclude `^` with the start of string `^`. Nor could I figure out the proper place to add the `|` operator, or if that was even the correct approach.)

Comment: Is there any reason to use regex for parsing JSON in JavaScript ? Also keys in JSON are supposed to be strings.

Comment: This is being applied after the JSON has been parsed to a string. And the end result for this is not JSON.

Comment: Why not just use: let obj = JSON.parse(str); to initialize your object?

Comment: Also parseInt(str) will yield "NaN" unless the string (str) begins with a number so I believe another option is to check the truthiness of !!parseInt(property) since NaN is falsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern doesn't work because `[^"0-9]+` requires all the character to be neither `"` nor a digit while you only want to make sure the first character is not a digit.

You may use the following pattern:

```
/"([^0-9][^"]*)":/g
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rcglbJ/1).

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex :
**Regex :**

```
\"([a-zA-Z]\w*)\"(?=:)
```

[image]

**Demo :** [Here](https://regex101.com/r/cTvQ4W/1)

Comment: Note that this will not match `"a":`. You should replace `\w+` with `\w*`.

Comment: Thank you! This one works as well (with the single property name exception mentioned above). And I appreciate the diagram. I'm going to accept the other answer as it's closer to the original pattern of telling what to exclude rather than include.