# Can I remove quotes only around keys and one value of stringified JSON.?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have this string

```
{"key1":"1","key2":"someString"}
```

I would like it to read:

```
{key1:1,key2:"someString"}
```

I can easily remove the quotes from everything. But I still need the second value with quotes around it for a graphql query in React. Sorry if my explanation in clear on why.

Comment: graphql can't have a proper object?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233498/json-stringify-without-quotes-on-properties

Answer (score 0):

To remove quotes from keys, you can use regex to replace `"\w+":` with with the word + colon:

```js
let input = '{"key1":"1","key2":"someString"}';
let output = input.replace(/"(\w+)":/g, '$1:');
console.log(output);
```

Per question edit, it seems numeric values also want quotes removed:

```js
let input = '{"key1":"1","key2":"someString"}';
let output = input
  .replace(/"(\w+)":/g, '$1:')
  .replace(/"(\d+)"/g, '$1');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: I edited my post. I also need the first value to have the quotes removed. This IS correct though for removing quotes from keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const
    input = '{"key1":"1","key2":"someString"}',
    output = '{' + Object.entries(JSON.parse(input)).map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${isNaN(Number(value)) ? `"${value}"` : value}`).join() + '}';
    
console.log(output);
```