# Need to display only values of json stringify object

Tags: node.js, json

Currently , in mycode `console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4))` is displaying the result as

```
[
   {  title: "title of the page",
      Link: "http: www.google.com",
      snippet:"this is google page"
    },
   { title: "title of the second page",
      Link: "http: www.yahoo.com",
      snippet:"this is yahoo page"
    },
    { title: "title of the third page",
      Link: "http: www.drive.com",
      snippet:"this is drive page"
    }
]
```

Now i need to remove the "[" and "{" "]" "}" in json response and also trim the "title,link,snippet".

The exact result i need is

```
   "title of the page",
   "http: www.google.com",
  "this is google page"

   "title of second page",
  "http: www.yahoo.com",
  "this is yahoo page"
```

Please suggest me , how to manipulate this  `JSON.stringify(response, null, 4))` to get the above result.

Comment: You can find a solution to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233498/json-stringify-without-quotes-on-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take would be like, loop through each index of the array, then get the object values:

```js
let data = [
   {  title: "title of the page",
      Link: "http: www.google.com",
      snippet:"this is google page"
    },
   { title: "title of the second page",
      Link: "http: www.yahoo.com",
      snippet:"this is yahoo page"
    },
    { title: "title of the third page",
      Link: "http: www.drive.com",
      snippet:"this is drive page"
    }
]
let str = ""

data.forEach( obj =>{ Object.values(obj).forEach( (val, key) =>{  str+='"'+val+'"'; key!=2?str+=',\n':str+='\n\n' })} )

console.log(str)
```

Comment: Thanks for information . it worked , one more thing i want to enable space between each object . I mean to beautifying the output... any thoughts

Comment: @thamizharasan, sure. I have edited the answer to include the spaces / next lines. please check

Comment: Great answer. Simple and short. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
response = [
   {  title: "title of the page",
      Link: "http: www.google.com",
      snippet:"this is google page"
    },
   { title: "title of the second page",
      Link: "http: www.yahoo.com",
      snippet:"this is yahoo page"
    },
    { title: "title of the third page",
      Link: "http: www.drive.com",
      snippet:"this is drive page"
    }
]
response.forEach(x => Object.values(x).forEach(console.log))
```