# Is there a way to send JSON data with the key not being in double quotes with Axios?

Tags: reactjs, json, authentication, axios

I'm trying to make an simple Login screen with my back-end already being done. The Login API is finished(after testing with POSTMan), however I've had issues with sending the JSON data back to my back-end in which it can read it.

```
const options = {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    "Accept": "application/json" }
}

axios.post('http://127.0.0.1/register/', 
{
  email: data.get('email'), 
  password: data.get('password'), 
  //SchoolID: '123456789' 
}, options)
```

While it does send the request data back to the server, unfortunately it sends it back in a way in which my back-end cannot read it.

```
"email" : "mytest@email.com" // How my front-end sends it 
email : "mytest@email.com"   // How I want it to be done(POSTMan does it this way)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you arent looking to have the backend handle it instead?

Comment: In any case this answer may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65443215/19192101

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with an external API. It seems that the JSON [RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) standard assumes that the key is surrounded by quotation marks. See examples at point 8. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to convince Axios to disable enclosing key names in quotation marks.

This is a JSON object:

```
  {
      "Image": {
          "Width":  800,
          "Height": 600,
          "Title":  "View from 15th Floor",
          "Thumbnail": {
              "Url":    "http://www.example.com/image/481989943",
              "Height": 125,
              "Width":  "100"
          },
          "IDs": [116, 943, 234, 38793]
      }
  }
```