# How to convert Array into array objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, canvasjs

Dears, this is my array:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{x: 2019, y: '0.50', label: 2019}
1
: 
{x: 2020, y: '0.00', label: 2020}
2
: 
{x: 2021, y: '3.80', label: 2021}
x
: 
0
length
: 
3
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

I need it in `[{ x: 2019, y: 0.50, label: "2019" }, { x: 2020, y: 0.00, label: "2020" }, { x: 2021, y: 3.80, label: "2021" },];` format.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: its already in the format you need?

Comment: Could you please explain what is the current format of your data?  Because from your message I get that you want an array of objects converted into an array of objects...

Comment: The only difference I see is `y` is converted from a string to a number while `label` is changed other way round. But, since this is for a chart, I don't think that's gonna matter much.

Comment: I suspect the "I have this" sample is copied from a browser console log, and is just how the log is displaying the data (which, apart from some string-to-number conversions, is the same data as in your  "I need it in" sample.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `JSON.stringify(arrayName)` method.

Example:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {
  x: 2019,
  y: '0.50',
  label: 2019
}
1: {
  x: 2020,
  y: '0.00',
  label: 2020
}
2: {
  x: 2021,
  y: '3.80',
  label: 2021
}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

After using `JSON.stringify(a)`output is:

```
'[{"x":2019,"y":"0.50","label":2019},{"x":2020,"y":"0.00","label":2020},{"x":2021,"y":"3.80","label":2021}]'
```

Comment: While passing data to canvasjs dataPoints data is going like "[{ x: 2019, y: 0.50, label: "2019" }, { x: 2020, y: 0.00, label: "2020" }, { x: 2021, y: 3.80, label: "2021" },]" format. I need that without double quotes. How to do this.

Comment: yes, we don't have any property to stringify without quotes. The solution can be to replace "" after using JSON.stringify 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233498/json-stringify-without-quotes-on-properties

Comment: This would convert the object into a JSON string, which is not at all what they were asking for.