# Memory friendly JSON validation in PHP

Tags: php, validation, json

I'm trying to validate a big piece of `JSON` in `PHP`.

There is no need to use the actual data, I just need to validate it.

I can not use `json_decode`, because it goes over the memory limit.

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Why would you validate it if you're not going to use it?

Comment: I validate it and then post to the server.

Comment: Regex? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json

Comment: I've just tried the regexp, and it didn't validate  JSON which was successfully decoded after it.

Comment: If your server allows it, perhaps you could run a script from the command line with the -d option, php -d memory_limit=<something_big> json_check.php

Comment: I'll still be stuck with the amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you could count the control structures (brackets and braces) and if the number of open/close structures are identical, you could make a partial bet that the JSON was OK.  There are lots of ways it could still be wrong, like improper nesting, but I think the only really good way of validating the string would be to decode it.  You might look into raising the memory limit, or having the author of the JSON send subsets so that you can decode the subsets and validate each partial component of the object.

Comment: Hi Ray, Thank you for the response, counting brackets won't help with unescaped quotes.

Comment: Where does the JSON string come from?

Comment: JSON comes from another server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a discussion about using a regexp for validation(without parse the content)  [Regex to validate JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json)

Comment: I've just tried the regexp, and it didn't validate JSON which was successfully decoded by json_decode after it.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to build a parser. Check out [this article](http://www.codediesel.com/php/building-a-simple-parser-and-lexer-in-php/) or do some research on the process of building a parser. Basically, that means defining a grammar for JSON (which is pretty much done for you at http://JSON.org) and then building functions to serve as checks for the corresponding machines to process each type of token. This will reduce the amount of memory required to do the processing (in an ideal implementation it could probably be down to the size of the largest JSON value).

It may be worthwhile to do some searching on Google to make sure you are not reinventing the wheel.