# Select Json Element from SQL using Regex Only

Tags: sql, regex, json

I need to write a SQL query that will take stored JSON in a table column and return just the array element. Problem is I can't use a JSON parser for this due to it being SQL Azure. I take it I will have to do this using regex.

Here is my Json stored in SQL

[{"IsPrimary":false,"Address":"test@test.com","Type":"Other"}]

I want to select out just the email address "test@test.com" only.

Comment: [`"SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming"`](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) a must read.

Comment: I want to select it out so I can write some script to get rid of this problem :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json

Comment: @lordkain that definitely won't work since SQL regex flavor is quite limited

Answer (score 0):

If you know upfront that your JSON string across all the rows will have the same "schema" / name:value pairs then yes, Regex might be the way to go.

On the other hand, if you are looking for a JSON deserializer inside of SQL Server, then check out this article that has the source code for a parseJSON() function for deserializing JSON.

**Simple-Talk.com**:  [Consuming JSON Strings in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/)

Might be definitely over-kill for what you are trying to do, but just so you know, it is possible and the source code works (I tried it on my localhost SQL Server on a variety of nested JSON strings.

Comment: It will be the same across the board.

Comment: SQL Server does not have built-in Regex support (you may be aware of this.). So your option is to either 1) write a CLR Function that does the Regex processing or 2) Try PATINDEX for simple Pattern matching and do a Substring. For #1, see here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx For #2, you'll have to try it out (trial and error). Not sure how it will work for empty values of "address".