# How to insert an array in a MySQL table with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, pdo

I need to migrate a JSON file that has my users data to a table in MySQL with PHP, I already did a connection, with the DB I created a table were y decode the JSON into an array. What I cannot do is insert the array data into the MySQL Users table.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "nombre":"asudhau",
    "apellido":"uhsaudhau",
    "pass":"$2y$10$KAg3wt7bBjphgdCNJf4VXe.an8lOnlOvWVdVsh2Qsws0dbhWiDwkO",
    "mail":"usaudha@hotmail.com",
    "sexo":"F",
    "id":34,
    "nacimiento":"2016-10-06"
}
{
    "nombre":"abudasd",
    "apellido":"hasdua",
    "pass":"$2y$10$c781KdL3ERgDCnP6MR28xuf\/dnKjuVajklc0uSj2FnBrZSB1H88Si",
    "mail":"uhasiuda@hotmail.com",
    "sexo":"F",
    "id":35,
    "nacimiento":"1990-02-03"
}
{
    "nombre":"audihaiudh",
    "apellido":"uiahsdiuahdi",
    "pass":"$2y$10$Q7VjafKxt\/kuJS1BrslF0uSZPwHe7Hvp6olMxetgY31KcmMT9dIo2",
    "mail":"hiuahdiuah@hotmail.com",
    "sexo":"F",
    "id":36,
    "nacimiento":"1999-02-03"
}
```

I got the values of each user this way:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dh_usuarios;charset=UTF8mb4', 'root', '');
   $jsondata = file_get_contents('../usuarios.json');
   $usuariosArray = explode(PHP_EOL, $jsondata);

    foreach ($usuariosArray as $usuario) {
      $jsondata = json_decode($usuario.PHP_EOL, true);
      $jsonarray[] = array($jsondata);
    }
      foreach ($jsonarray as $row) {

      $nombre = $row[0]['nombre'];
      $apellido = $row[0]['apellido'];
      $pass = $row[0]['pass'];
      $mail = $row[0]['mail'];
      $sexo = $row[0]['sexo'];
      $id = $row[0]['id'];
      $nacimiento = $row[0]['nacimiento'];
}
```

Now I want to insert this users data to a table that i have already created in MySQL and I don't know how to do it.

I tried this, but it just doesn't insert the data.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('
    INSERT INTO dh_usuarios(nombre, apellido, pass, mail, sexo, id, nacimiento)
    VALUES(:nombre, :apellido, :pass, :mail, :sexo, :id, :nacimiento);
   ');

  $stmt->execute([
    ':nombre' => $nombre,
    ':apellido' => $apellido,
    ':pass' => $pass,
    ':mail' => $mail,
    ':sexo' => $sexo,
    ':id' => $id,
    ':nacimiento' => $nacimiento,
  ]
);
```

Help me what should I do?
(sorry for my bad English, I'm from Argentina)

Comment: Did you check for errors from the DB?

Comment: i don't seems to be an error from the database, i think i made a mistake somewhere but i can't figure it out....

Comment: Try `var_dump($jsondata)` to check if you have something there.

Comment: yes, there is the array

Comment: ok. Then try to `echo $jsonarray[0]['nombre']`... If it's ok, then check if there is a PDO error. Add this after "execute" : `if (!$stmt) { print_r($conn->errorInfo()); }else{ echo "stmt is ok."; }`

Comment: If all this don't work... Check if the database user has insert priviledge. Then... I will not know what else to check ;)

Comment: mmm... There's an extra coma `,` at the end of `':nacimiento' => $nacimiento,`... Maybe ?? I just saw it.

Comment: when i echo $jsonarray[0]['nombre'], it goes Notice: Undefined index: nombre, what does that means?

Comment: If i check the PDO, with if (!$stmt) { print_r($conn->errorInfo()); }else{ echo "stmt is ok."; }, it says "stmt is okstmt is okstmt is ok........." the times the foreach is iterating....

Comment: It's a good thing about "stmt is ok". Remove all `[0]`. The array you have there is an associative array. Example : key=nombre and value=asudhau. The `[0]` was specifing to check for key=0... Which is undefined. So I think you found your problem! Have a look at what Grandpalako says below in his answer. It's relevant. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix your code.

## 1) Fixing JSON format *(recommended)*

Your JSON file is not valid, you have multiple root elements. If you can change it, that would be the first step to do:

```
[
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

After you fixed the format of your JSON file, you can simplify your PHP code. The following part:

```
$usuariosArray = explode(PHP_EOL, $jsondata);



foreach ($usuariosArray as $usuario) {
    $jsondata = json_decode($usuario.PHP_EOL, true);
         $jsonarray[] = array($jsondata);
    }
}
```

becomes:

```
$jsonarray = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

Now you can loop through the array (please notice that `[0]` index has been removed):

```
foreach ($jsonarray as $row) {
    $nombre = $row['nombre'];
    $apellido = $row['apellido'];
    $pass = $row['pass'];
    $mail = $row['mail'];
    $sexo = $row['sexo'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $nacimiento = $row['nacimiento'];
}
```

## 2) Replacing explode with regex

If you can't fix the format of your JSON file, `explode()` needs to be replaced because it currently explodes the JSON file by each row (you are using end of line character as delimiter).

With using `preg_match_all` you can retrieve each object from your invalid JSON file, using a [complex (and not bulletproof) regex pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994677/find-json-strings-in-a-string):

```
$pattern = '
/
\{              # { character
    (?:         # non-capturing group
        [^{}]   # anything that is not a { or }
        |       # OR
        (?R)    # recurses the entire pattern
    )*          # previous group zero or more times
\}              # } character
/x
';

preg_match_all($pattern, $jsondata, $matches);
```

Now you can loop through your `$matches` and decode them as JSON:

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
  $jsonarray[] = json_decode($match, true);
}
```

The last step is the same as above.

Comment: I change everything as you say but still doesnt insert it to the table...