# How to get json from a string?

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
"var block = new MatchesBlock('page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_5', 'block_competition_matches_summary', {"page":0,"bookmaker_urls":{"13":[{"link":"http:\/\/www.bet365.com\/home\/?affiliate=365_178981","name":"Bet 365"}]},"block_service_id":"competition_summary_block_competitionmatchessummary","round_id":42011,"outgroup":false,"view":2,"competition_id":13});"
```

I want get:

```
{"page":0,"bookmaker_urls":{"13":[{"link":"http:\/\/www.bet365.com\/home\/?affiliate=365_178981","name":"Bet 365"}]},"block_service_id":"competition_summary_block_competitionmatchessummary","round_id":42011,"outgroup":false,"view":2,"competition_id":13}
```

so I write:

```
MatchesBlock\(([^)]+)\)
```

but this will take all the string inside `MatchesBlock`

Comment: Check out the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994677/find-json-strings-in-a-string I hope it helps.

Comment: @GeorgeGabriel I use `\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}` won't work

Comment: Please tag your question with a lang or a tool.

Comment: In the general case, you cannot do this; JSON is not a regular language and cannot be parsed with regular expressions. If the JSON happens to be the only place that curly braces show up and it will always be a JSON object at the top level, then it's possible, but we need more details to know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example provided, you can use:

```
{[^)]+
```

---

### [image]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TsDqbr/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that regex is greedy by default and use

[`MatchesBlock[^\{]+\K(.*})`](https://regex101.com/r/XDcnk4/3)

Here I use `\K` to reset the match, i.e. anything before `\K` will not be captured.

Comment: This doesn't do what he asked. He does **NOT** want `MatchesBlock` or the other parameters to be captured. He only wants the JSON.

Comment: How did you know that OP's end regex flavor supports `\K`?

Comment: As you correctly mentioned in other comment, I'd suggest the OP to post his/her prog. language.   OP can determine if `\K` is supported from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex

Comment: OP said in his / her comment he / she can't have that regex to work. If that regex does not work for him / her then `\K` wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to extract the JSON from your `MatchesBlock` constructor parameters, simply use the following regex:

`\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}`

Input:

```
var block = new MatchesBlock('page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_5', 'block_competition_matches_summary', {"page":0,"bookmaker_urls":{"13":[{"link":"http:\/\/www.bet365.com\/home\/?affiliate=365_178981","name":"Bet 365"}]},"block_service_id":"competition_summary_block_competitionmatchessummary","round_id":42011,"outgroup":false,"view":2,"competition_id":13});
```

Output:

```
{"page":0,"bookmaker_urls":{"13":[{"link":"http:\/\/www.bet365.com\/home\/?affiliate=365_178981","name":"Bet 365"}]},"block_service_id":"competition_summary_block_competitionmatchessummary","round_id":42011,"outgroup":false,"view":2,"competition_id":13}
```