# PHP: http raw POST data contain BINARY

Tags: php

i have a device that send POST data to my server.
so **print_r($_POST)** is empty, i can see the data only when i run this

```
$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($content);   

//or i can use:  print_r($content);
```

i save those to a file and result are some json and BINARY DATA (CHECK IMAGE)[image: SCREENSHOT]

if i add code like this **json_decode($content,true);** i dont see anything

so how can i decode binary or what can i do to decode the json and also see what data is send in binary?

Comment: can you add attachment?

Comment: u can check now

Comment: You need to try and search that input to look for a valid structure. Then parse THAT. Might I recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994677/find-json-strings-in-a-string)?

Comment: Is there no documentation for this _device_? What is it supposed to be sending? What is the HTTP request `Content-type` header? It _should_ be available in `$_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE']`

Comment: [Content-Type] => application/octet-stream, application/octet-stream

Comment: Damn, I had a feeling it was going to be that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to decode binary data in`PHP`, try the following:

```
<?php
$binarydata = "\x04\x00\xa0\x00";
$data = unpack('C*', $binarydata);
var_dump($data);
```

output:

```
array (size=4)
  1 => int 4
  2 => int 0
  3 => int 160
  4 => int 0
```

Load your contents from file_get_contents('php://input') to $binarydata and you will get an array of values. You can then apply some logic to extract JSON string and process it.

Comment: array(125) { [1]=> int(121) [2]=> int(0) [3]=> int(0) [4]=> int(0) [5]=> int(123) [6]=> int(34) [7]=> int(102) ................int(125) [124]=> int(10) [125]=> int(0) }
so what to do with those

Comment: these are bytes, which are built from bits (8 bits = 1 byte). For example string "enroll", which is what you will probably be looking for is represented by the following:
char 101, 110, 114, 111, 108, 108 
ascii  e     n      r       o     l        l