# JS regex to find json strings in a text

Tags: javascript, json

How to convert this `{(?:[^{}]*|(?R))*}` PCRE regex to js regex without any external library?

[Find JSON strings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994677/find-json-strings-in-a-string)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: JSON isn't a regular language, which means you can't use a regex on it without it being fragile.