# Check if string is valid JSON?

Tags: php, json

How can I check if it is a valid json before it has been decoded, like in case of an array we can check with  is_array(); can we do something similar in PHP?

Comment: `$valid=json_decode($json)` if valid is false then its a no go

Comment: Perhaps look into regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json

Answer (score -1):

First `decode` the `string` with `oppressor`. If it gives `true` then it is valid `else` invalid. Also cane use [json_last_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php). You can check by this way..

```
$str = 'your json string';
$test = @json_decode($str);
if($test){
   echo 'Valid';
}else{
   echo 'not valid';
}
```

Comment: +1 the warnings wouldn't *dare* show themselves after being oppressed

Comment: That by itself it not really enough. `[]` is a valid JSON string but would fail your test. The return value is not "`true`", it's the decoded value, which could be a number of things. There's no need for `@` either, since `json_decode` doesn't trigger warnings AFAIK.

Comment: Hello, i want to check before it has been decoded. Your solution checks if the decoded value is present or not.

Comment: What would be the purpose of checking before decoding exactly? I suppose you would want to decode and use it if it is valid, no?

Comment: Helo, In same db column there is JSON and other normal string aswell. So it's tryig to decode normal string aswell, and its showing error. So i want to check if it is just JSON and do other stuff.