# Checking if a string is valid json before trying to parse it?

Tags: ruby, json

In Ruby, is there a way to check if a string is valid json before trying to parse it?

For example getting some information from some other urls, sometimes it returns json, sometimes it could return a garbage which is not a valid response.

My code:

```
def get_parsed_response(response)
  parsed_response = JSON.parse(response)
end
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure parsing it is the only way to know for sure it's valid. Why not parse it and handle the parsing error telling you it's invalid?

Comment: for example this way `JSON.parse(string) rescue nil`

Comment: Theoretically, there should be a way. Parsing a string results in a properly stronger information than knowing whether it is parsable or not. In Chomsky's term, regarding natural language, this distinction corresponds to strong versus weak generative capacity. However, what's wrong with rescuing the error as with the comments above?

Comment: Or you could use a [Regex to validate JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json)

Comment: @gotva - Can you give me the correct rescue syntax?

Comment: above is a short syntax. If you would like to handle exception more accurate look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gotva/42c32c418f7a05398957)

Comment: Technically speaking, the process of determining whether a string is valid in a language *is* parsing. Building a data-structure telling you *how* it is valid is actually just a side-effect of that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag There are ways to determine if a string is parsable without parsing it. For example, consider a language that consists of the alphabet `a` and `b`, and whose BNF is (something like) `S := aSa|b`. You can tell whether a string confirms to this language by just seeing that there is exactly one `b`, and the numbers of `a` on both sides of it are the same. That does not mean that you have the tree. Parsing means you have the tree structure.

Answer (score 91):

You can create a method to do the checking:

```
def valid_json?(json)
  JSON.parse(json)
  true
rescue JSON::ParserError, TypeError => e
  false
end
```

Comment: rescuing Exception is dangerous. It should only be used if absolutely necessary. Instead rescue several exceptions, like so:
rescue TypeError, JSON::ParserError, etc.

Comment: no need to use "begin". def - rescue - end should work

Comment: Thank you Taufiq Muhammadi. Made my answer better.

Comment: You don't need the "return" either.

Answer (score 31):

You can parse it this way

```
begin
  JSON.parse(string)  
rescue JSON::ParserError => e  
  # do smth
end 

# or for method get_parsed_response

def get_parsed_response(response)
  parsed_response = JSON.parse(response)
rescue JSON::ParserError => e  
  # do smth
end
```

Comment: Please note that there may be 'TypeError' if under <string> there would be something that cannot be implicitly converted to string(e.g. nil)

Answer (score 14):

I think `parse_json` should return `nil` if it's invalid and shouldn't error out.

```
def parse_json string
  JSON.parse(string) rescue nil
end

unless json = parse_json string
  parse_a_different_way
end
```

Comment: Because its prettier... in fact, I'm considering opening up JSON and creating a method called parse_without_error.

Comment: Note that `null` and `false` are valid JSON, too. `JSON.parse` returns `nil` and `false` which would be treated as a parse error in the code above.

Answer (score 5):

Let me suggest a shorter variant

```
def valid_json?(string)
  !!(JSON.parse(string) || true) rescue false
end

> valid_json?("test")
=> false

> valid_json?("{\"mail_id\": \"999129237\", \"public_id\": \"166118134802\"}")
=> true

> valid_json?("false")
=> true
```