# How to print an api response which can be either JSON or non-JSON in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, response

I have a method which outputs api reponse. The response could be either a `JSON` response or non-JSON response. For JSON response, my code is as follows:

```
def process
  if success?
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  else
    handle_failure
  end
end
```

And for non-JSON response, I used 'eval' as:

```
def process
  if success?
    eval(response.body)
  else
    handle_failure
  end
end
```

But since response could be anything, how can I make sure that it prints the response in both case?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the method from [Checking if a string is valid json before trying to parse it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232909/checking-if-a-string-is-valid-json-before-trying-to-parse-it), define a method to check if the body is a JSON or not:

```
def valid_json?(json)
  JSON.parse(json)
  return true
rescue JSON::ParserError => e
  return false
end
```

In your class above you can then do:

```
def process
  valid_json?(response.body) ? process_json : process_non_json
end

def valid_json?(json)
  JSON.parse(json)
  return true
rescue JSON::ParserError => e
  return false
end

def process_json
  if success?
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  else
    handle_failure
  end
end

def process_non_json
  if success?
    eval(response.body)
  else
    handle_failure
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks alot @mark. Such a clean and neat technique!

Comment: Happy to help :)