# Regex pattern for JSON DATA format angular 6

Tags: json, regex, angular6

I am new who is using json but I what I tried is below.

[image: i am using this, i don't know this is true or not i found it from stackoverflow but it won't work]

[image: it is not validate my correct json format]

Comment: JSON keys need to be wrapped in doubles quotes `"` and the same goes for string values. So payload should be `{"kfl": "asdfads", "asdfklas": 123}`. For more info read https://www.json.org/

Comment: http://prntscr.com/m0jzo1 still not working, can you just check the pattern, is that true for json validation

Comment: You're not handling numeric values with your regex (the values must be quoted as per your regex, but a number in JSON shouldn't). It would also match `{ "var": "val" "missing":"comma" }` which it shouldn't. It would also fail to understand escaped quotes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json

Comment: I don't know how Angular validators work, but I urge you if possible to craft one based on whether JSON.parse raises an error when handling your payload rather than using regex. The "complete validation" of the accepted answer of the question linked by @GabrielePetrioli won't work as far as I know, JS regex engine not being the one with the most features

Comment: thanks for try to help me, but I found the solution, will post answer soon

Comment: found solution something like your opinion @Aaron

Comment: Nice, you're making a custom validator then? Looked it up a little bit, I'm looking forward to your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

calling function on keyup and change event

[image]

use parser which will parse only if data is in json format and set **parseError = true**

otherwise it'll goto the catch section and set **parseError = false**

set error message based of **parseError**