# How to use regex to get JSON value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, regex

Im currently trying to learn to get JSON value from a website which has a script that within JSON inside it which im trying to get with regex.

For now I have tried to do: `jsonConfig":\s*.*}` which does find a match but does not group it (Which means I cannot get the values to later on parse it with json.loads which I will show at the very bottom of this thread)

```
"Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer": {
                "jsonConfig": {"attributes":{"203":{"id":"203","code":"sizefootwear_conf","label":"EU","options":[{"id":"6320","label":"38","products":["69813"]},{"id":"6351","label":"38,5","products":["69817"]},{"id":"6335","label":"39","products":["69818"]},{"id":"6354","label":"40","products":["69819"]},{"id":"6338","label":"40,5","products":["69820"]},{"id":"6357","label":"41","products":["69821"]},{"id":"6326","label":"42","products":["69822"]},{"id":"6362","label":"42,5","products":["69823"]},{"id":"6341","label":"43","products":["69824"]},{"id":"6365","label":"44","products":["69814"]},{"id":"6344","label":"44,5","products":["69815"]},{"id":"6370","label":"45,5","products":["69816"]}],"position":"0"},"205":{"id":"205","code":"sizefootwearus_conf","label":"US","options":[{"id":"6319","label":"5,5","products":["69813"]},{"id":"6372","label":"6,0","products":["69817"]},{"id":"6334","label":"6,5","products":["69818"]},{"id":"6350","label":"7,0","products":["69819"]},{"id":"6337","label":"7,5","products":["69820"]},{"id":"6353","label":"8,0","products":["69821"]},{"id":"6325","label":"8,5","products":["69822"]},{"id":"6356","label":"9,0","products":["69823"]},{"id":"6340","label":"9,5","products":["69824"]},{"id":"6364","label":"10,0","products":["69814"]},{"id":"6343","label":"10,5","products":["69815"]},{"id":"6328","label":"11,5","products":["69816"]}],"position":"1"},"204":{"id":"204","code":"sizefootwearuk_conf","label":"UK","options":[{"id":"6318","label":"5,0","products":["69813"]},{"id":"6352","label":"5,5","products":["69817"]},{"id":"6743","label":"6,0-EU39","products":["69818"]},{"id":"6744","label":"6,0-EU40","products":["69819"]},{"id":"6355","label":"6,5","products":["69820"]},{"id":"6336","label":"7,0","products":["69821"]},{"id":"6361","label":"7,5","products":["69822"]},{"id":"6324","label":"8,0","products":["69823"]},{"id":"6363","label":"8,5","products":["69824"]},{"id":"6339","label":"9,0","products":["69814"]},{"id":"6366","label":"9,5","products":["69815"]},{"id":"6369","label":"10,5","products":["69816"]}],"position":"2"}},"template":"\u20ac<%- data.price %>","currencyFormat":"\u20ac%s","optionPrices":{"69813":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69814":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69815":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69816":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69817":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69818":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69819":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69820":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69821":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69822":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69823":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69824":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}}},"priceFormat":{"pattern":"\u20ac%s","precision":2,"requiredPrecision":2,"decimalSymbol":".","groupSymbol":",","groupLength":3,"integerRequired":false},"prices":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99}},"productId":"69825","chooseText":"Choose an Option...","images":[],"index":{"69813":{"203":"6320","205":"6319","204":"6318"},"69814":{"203":"6365","205":"6364","204":"6339"},"69815":{"203":"6344","205":"6343","204":"6366"},"69816":{"203":"6370","205":"6328","204":"6369"},"69817":{"203":"6351","205":"6372","204":"6352"},"69818":{"203":"6335","205":"6334","204":"6743"},"69819":{"203":"6354","205":"6350","204":"6744"},"69820":{"203":"6338","205":"6337","204":"6355"},"69821":{"203":"6357","205":"6353","204":"6336"},"69822":{"203":"6326","205":"6325","204":"6361"},"69823":{"203":"6362","205":"6356","204":"6324"},"69824":{"203":"6341","205":"6340","204":"6363"}},"productStockAlert":{"entity":"69825","map":{"203":{"label":"52,5","":"","6610":"6610","6498":"6498","6582":"6582","6516":"6516","6501":"6501","6518":"6518","6504":"6504","6395":"6395","6404":"6404","6533":"6533","6407":"6407","6530":"6530","6410":"6410","6413":"6413","6416":"6416","6534":"6534","6419":"6419","6422":"6422","6425":"6425","6398":"6398","6401":"6401","6531":"6531","6431":"6431","6443":"6443","6446":"6446","6495":"6495","6449":"6449","6452":"6452","6455":"6455","6458":"6458","6461":"6461","6807":"6807","6464":"6464","6434":"6434","6437":"6437","6558":"6558","6440":"6440","6480":"6480","6481":"6481","6382":"6382","6465":"6465","6631":"6631","6332":"6332","6466":"6466","6348":"6348","6634":"6634","6320":"6320","6351":"6351","6384":"6384","6659":"6659","6335":"6335","6388":"6388","6508":"6508","6354":"6354","6338":"6338","6389":"6389","6664":"6664","6357":"6357","6390":"6390","6506":"6506","6637":"6637","6326":"6326","6362":"6362","6391":"6391","6640":"6640","6341":"6341","6392":"6392","6560":"6560","6365":"6365","6344":"6344","6385":"6385","6838":"6838","6368":"6368","6386":"6386","6370":"6370","6643":"6643","6628":"6628","6329":"6329","6529":"6529","6387":"6387","6843":"6843","6347":"6347","6470":"6470","6360":"6360","6646":"6646","6472":"6472","6323":"6323","6564":"6564","6593":"6593","6474":"6474","6376":"6376","6565":"6565","6561":"6561","6567":"6567","6604":"6604","6607":"6607"},"205":{"label":"18,0","":"","6513":"6513","6497":"6497","6583":"6583","6500":"6500","6821":"6821","6503":"6503","6532":"6532","6394":"6394","6403":"6403","6406":"6406","6409":"6409","6412":"6412","6415":"6415","6418":"6418","6421":"6421","6424":"6424","6397":"6397","6400":"6400","6430":"6430","6442":"6442","6445":"6445","6448":"6448","6451":"6451","6454":"6454","6457":"6457","6460":"6460","6463":"6463","6433":"6433","6436":"6436","6439":"6439","6555":"6555","6468":"6468","6507":"6507","6632":"6632","6331":"6331","6319":"6319","6635":"6635","6372":"6372","6334":"6334","6661":"6661","6350":"6350","6337":"6337","6663":"6663","6353":"6353","6619":"6619","6325":"6325","6621":"6621","6638":"6638","6356":"6356","6340":"6340","6623":"6623","6641":"6641","6364":"6364","6343":"6343","6625":"6625","6840":"6840","6367":"6367","6328":"6328","6644":"6644","6371":"6371","6346":"6346","6842":"6842","6359":"6359","6322":"6322","6647":"6647","6373":"6373","6566":"6566","6375":"6375","6562":"6562","6605":"6605","6608":"6608"},"204":{"label":"17,0","":"","6611":"6611","6514":"6514","6496":"6496","6515":"6515","6499":"6499","6517":"6517","6502":"6502","6393":"6393","6505":"6505","6402":"6402","6405":"6405","6408":"6408","6411":"6411","6414":"6414","6417":"6417","6420":"6420","6423":"6423","6396":"6396","6399":"6399","6429":"6429","6745":"6745","6441":"6441","6444":"6444","6447":"6447","6450":"6450","6453":"6453","6456":"6456","6459":"6459","6462":"6462","6432":"6432","6435":"6435","6438":"6438","6467":"6467","6381":"6381","6633":"6633","6330":"6330","6349":"6349","6636":"6636","6318":"6318","6352":"6352","6660":"6660","6333":"6333","6743":"6743","6744":"6744","6355":"6355","6662":"6662","6336":"6336","6620":"6620","6361":"6361","6622":"6622","6639":"6639","6324":"6324","6363":"6363","6624":"6624","6642":"6642","6339":"6339","6366":"6366","6626":"6626","6839":"6839","6342":"6342","6627":"6627","6369":"6369","6645":"6645","6327":"6327","6358":"6358","6841":"6841","6345":"6345","6471":"6471","6648":"6648","6321":"6321","6473":"6473","6374":"6374","6563":"6563","6606":"6606","6609":"6609"}},"child":{"6320_6319_6318_":{"entity":"69813","stock_number":0,"stock_status":false,"productId":"69813","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6365_6364_6339_":{"entity":"69814","stock_number":5,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69814","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6344_6343_6366_":{"entity":"69815","stock_number":3,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69815","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6370_6328_6369_":{"entity":"69816","stock_number":1,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69816","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6351_6372_6352_":{"entity":"69817","stock_number":0,"stock_status":false,"productId":"69817","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6335_6334_6743_":{"entity":"69818","stock_number":0,"stock_status":false,"productId":"69818","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6354_6350_6744_":{"entity":"69819","stock_number":0,"stock_status":false,"productId":"69819","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6338_6337_6355_":{"entity":"69820","stock_number":0,"stock_status":false,"productId":"69820","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6357_6353_6336_":{"entity":"69821","stock_number":3,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69821","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6326_6325_6361_":{"entity":"69822","stock_number":4,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69822","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6362_6356_6324_":{"entity":"69823","stock_number":6,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69823","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6341_6340_6363_":{"entity":"69824","stock_number":6,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69824","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"}}},"stock":{"69813":0,"69814":5,"69815":3,"69816":1,"69817":0,"69818":0,"69819":0,"69820":0,"69821":3,"69822":4,"69823":6,"69824":6}},
                "jsonSwatchConfig": {"203":{"6320":{"type":"0","value":"38","label":"38"},"6351":{"type":"0","value":"38,5","label":"38,5"},"6335":{"type":"0","value":"39","label":"39"},"6354":{"type":"0","value":"40","label":"40"},"6338":{"type":"0","value":"40,5","label":"40,5"},"6357":{"type":"0","value":"41","label":"41"},"6326":{"type":"0","value":"42","label":"42"},"6362":{"type":"0","value":"42,5","label":"42,5"},"6341":{"type":"0","value":"43","label":"43"},"6365":{"type":"0","value":"44","label":"44"},"6344":{"type":"0","value":"44,5","label":"44,5"},"6370":{"type":"0","value":"45,5","label":"45,5"},"additional_data":"{\"swatch_input_type\":\"text\",\"update_product_preview_image\":\"0\",\"use_product_image_for_swatch\":0}"},"205":{"6319":{"type":"0","value":"5,5","label":"5,5"},"6372":{"type":"0","value":"6,0","label":"6,0"},"6334":{"type":"0","value":"6,5","label":"6,5"},"6350":{"type":"0","value":"7,0","label":"7,0"},"6337":{"type":"0","value":"7,5","label":"7,5"},"6353":{"type":"0","value":"8,0","label":"8,0"},"6325":{"type":"0","value":"8,5","label":"8,5"},"6356":{"type":"0","value":"9,0","label":"9,0"},"6340":{"type":"0","value":"9,5","label":"9,5"},"6364":{"type":"0","value":"10,0","label":"10,0"},"6343":{"type":"0","value":"10,5","label":"10,5"},"6328":{"type":"0","value":"11,5","label":"11,5"},"additional_data":"{\"swatch_input_type\":\"text\",\"update_product_preview_image\":\"0\",\"use_product_image_for_swatch\":0}"},"204":{"6318":{"type":"0","value":"5,0","label":"5,0"},"6352":{"type":"0","value":"5,5","label":"5,5"},"6743":{"type":"0","value":"6,0-EU39","label":"6,0-EU39"},"6744":{"type":"0","value":"6,0-EU40","label":"6,0-EU40"},"6355":{"type":"0","value":"6,5","label":"6,5"},"6336":{"type":"0","value":"7,0","label":"7,0"},"6361":{"type":"0","value":"7,5","label":"7,5"},"6324":{"type":"0","value":"8,0","label":"8,0"},"6363":{"type":"0","value":"8,5","label":"8,5"},"6339":{"type":"0","value":"9,0","label":"9,0"},"6366":{"type":"0","value":"9,5","label":"9,5"},"6369":{"type":"0","value":"10,5","label":"10,5"},"additional_data":"{\"swatch_input_type\":\"text\",\"update_product_preview_image\":\"0\",\"use_product_image_for_swatch\":0}"}},
                "mediaCallback": "https\u003A\u002F\u002Fwww.bstn.com\u002Feu_en\u002Fswatches\u002Fajax\u002Fmedia\u002F",
                "gallerySwitchStrategy": "prepend",
                "jsonSwatchImageSizeConfig": {"swatchImage":{"width":30,"height":20},"swatchThumb":{"height":90,"width":110}},
                "showTooltip": 1
```

Im trying to get the `"jsonConfig":`value and I wonder how I can be able to do it using regex which I later on will use:

```
getJsonConfig= json.loads(
                    '{}'.format(
                        re.search(
                            r'`jsonConfig":\s*.*}',
                        response.text,
                        re.M | re.S
                    ).group(1)
                )
            )
```

Comment: standard regex are no powerful enough to match json structures. Implementations like PCRE can parse json, but I wouldn't got his route as maintenance is hard and error-prone. Could you show the full input? Maybe there is something we can use to avoid having to use regex to this end. Anyway, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json

Comment: @PEdroArthur to make it easier I think we can assume that the JSON is valid out of the html I have sent in my thread. I would be more than happy to just get the whole json from "jsonConfig" :)

Comment: The point is that a simple regex like the one suggested in the accepted answer is not powerful enough correctly capture the contents. For example, if for some reason `jsonConfig` and `jsonSwatchConfig` come in the same line, that regex fails. So, you need some guarantees you are consuming valid values.

Comment: @PEdroArthur The regex in the answer is the same as the regex in the question, it just shows the question author how to add a capturing group and extract the group value, and is not meant to match any arbitrary JSON.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this doesn't make the solution less bogus. There is probably a better and robust way to get this value and we should convince the author to provide more details so we can find the solution. Instead, people are convincing the authors that such simple regex is an acceptable approach, while it will certainly fail when this webpage get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the contents with parentheses:

```py
r'"jsonConfig":\s*(.*})'
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/DbNkwH/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "jsonConfig":            '"jsonConfig":'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }                        '}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##zVtRb9s4En7vrzAEFGkXTkKJQ4oK7g5YFLvA4u5wh0v7VBeGYiuJsrblk@RN00K/vUfyo2TKltdJHnLJQ2SaM@TM6JuPI4peP9S3xYr/@JEv10VZj8psfFcVqzdVXearm9FfR@XJyUnwz/QmW9XF9PI@rWe3WXV@V51X9vNpma3mWZmVwcXo@5vRzl9gxvpQrK7zG9MfpLUe9mpTZ1Vw8T2IGDeXfB5c2M/jYFbMM92o8m/ZdVHU91laTmdaXXct0qtsoft@@aQbxbrOi5Ue5LNTlzxinhBXurEui/lmVhupQCYq5MGXZtzJi7AnPxYDGnFPgwtfIxmQV/0ZyJMnNiCf9MdXPfkhi7STvRliXyMckA978pH05aMB@agnL6Oe/KBF/aiSH1XiA/LUn8GPKdFAjPry1IspDd410dOIfVyQGNSQWuOL/rqocoMrLciCZqwxKTx8imF8bqpdhH66HEZomHhCw4b0gxn74Zdjdhyh1FMQxyHqBycePwKjcU/hERDlnoIammEXo6KnII6CVPigTgZn2MEo6ymI4yD1wxqywTDtwJT3NY7DNPKTPwwfCdMQMCUPpnQApr/vwfTvB2CqejBlx5k0OorrHkzjXnQ0rk9/@XScTmOiPa1HkKoQx1JiB7BcHkuJHcDK8GhK9AEb0dGU6AdY8qMp0YcfT46lxA5epTyWEjtwlclxgO/DNQoajdc6W64XaW0QOtlELJ395e3paJ7W6dm6zGfZ6O3fDIQ3pa4sZg@/FuUyrTvRt1UH2n8bYVtHAJL6Q7GY22/N53RZbFZaMeTJWZLoaa/SKtvvDeMzyZUURDIKlRa7zlfp4vAodZ6V7cyftXfLqlzvSa82i4XxFIF@pYaJ12qYfK2Gxa/VMPVaDUteqWGa81@pYeFrNSx6rYa9VuaPXiHzN2aV1j3tqvo9WOtH8qxc9RfYdZnN8squ2dE4KLP/bvIy03743851Y5kuLh@WV4UpAs603k1ZbNbdN@P2m39kq5v6Nrjg4yBf1dlNVv7HDRlcXKeLKmvNql4kYk1Xqvxmixl9q@yz3W1RVNnH7KupNj7Yxihdjf5li42zM@OfdvimjXK@mmdfe9WH3c5odyLss2P70GcrdJTWflXQKtiH4FbBPmy0CrqQ81frVoHIU7DVdKugCzl/FW0VYt8k@6jRKXQzxL6C3R1pFexzaKugq31/1WkVuO8D93ww1b6/GnQz@D4I5itQ4LN0N4PyZ4h9k0Tgs2c3Q@zP4EeJt1ECq3U3TvpREn6UwsBnm@7GRf4M0lOIOh96d5r8sBLzZ@CBB8zLupj9/vMiK22OZqs6rx88qC7Ttbd/1j16YYNGf9L/pQyZ0TAX3aJEmZa56JZQkWmZi2kZrOBiWiy0LRaiT6EPejBW2IdMyRP4kQg7A/oIfYJbh83F9sXoi9HH0AfLYCc5O0OOFvRgGTnLOGa36NJfJuhLbCuyHpmLbQm0BOxUsFPBlhC2wD8Ob7ltEVrkWgRbCLYQbCGJeGIG5zvBFoItArYI2CIgKSApcB8EbJGYzz5CSoUoKUSJJOIp4S18J@c7Rzw54okxhRuTEE9CPBVayrUwn7LzcaCAAwUkYaclIykRCYlIcA5J7iQRCfvQqGGM6JKCHkEPCInYlhEtqXTcoqcF8JWVlMJG0FzGYJOOVLQIZlAOg/CWKYxJWzaxHNFRhVZIoGfHlIinRDwNOXQcoaEBOxOGGZAPTMKjGB5BMpJbqrAE0PGAVod/ifVP4j5I3AeT@R0BaBHoJcg/iXyQkJRiuyhYqu8YX7uCPmX7FLxVzlsJ36XzHXYq2Bmz7TKgTeKwzOJaRlZPRtCLELPIxkygJdDiCjFTNhIKoyiMwgl9BOxiPoqdR5hdutklZkcexciVGBGMHBFzxAX5jjsmEjBKgmyMkQ8x4hLD2xg8gQgKRFAgxwRyTMgYLWunBGdJcJZE/pnLdvO32@PARo0jVwGaEo6mEqRjgnRU6FNwguHmMuu8XaFwsX2QZJBEkgnuwIQbnyDhIUnM0SkSEAAlBvJhIJ8QAQ2RqiGSOgT5gMwJZE6whWALRQho5KgdtxMeEXwg@ECgb3L0TZiPMB9hPnK0iPlADYT0J6Q/IXEJiUtIRxKO@jADAEMSvkv4joWF3MLCEQmOSHBEggO8IF7hiBfpQdKRCGAAqpWIvHSRB/VxR31YZlDHaREBSSQnwMsdeDltix/NMyBQwM4UOF2dY6uXrojRIkhH@GcKla5e0dqgRczOI6800RmLGXD/JMhAOjIQcluT2EqjKzi0AuZDkkkQk3TEJGlbhNrSsqswtQJ8x@wKYypHb0grLh1Jqm2hqYdGkjkKixHdGPOBDDjIQAFLCljiWBK4WxKwwHMs8BJ0I0E3PHZVrqMN0LdbnmJXwzoyQI6BsCUKMckQTyws5rLdVO/SP/bTX4YIWuhqJPBUCCgngGQCLkICCpeACQCaAKAhQBiCNhhMYy794VLiSASjMFdpIeUgSeijtg8wx@pIsJNgJ8FOcnZidsLshJWasFITIEKACIdHHB5x@MATV3fBI6wQMdI/btMfs5OrpjA7YEC4geTWC6QHIT0IKUBIAQKUCVAmgIIACsLtJNxOQhqTq1KQqoRUJaQHcVd3YXYHV1RFXLlEQnqAYDjIjnO3isN3cmSAlQzkw0GueH1iH5O6dyM6t1ELuBWeuwcajpjx7UsR@/DTveywTzbdSwytDppy1QZmx/sK/R1mcJUWyAevJvSX0HOpA5KU3KUVbd9J2KeQ7oWDVkDiok8iOaVLTozC3ShIObxG0AqIC2okBUnlJDEKxygyQhpHuA8y2b5b0BMhOYElDknuJFHxclS8CjhTjsLIPV3hvoNuKHY1GVKcXK2DKLkFECRCIBGO@oKjvhCIi3BxwfIrXX2I5ddczAPc7DZfzO22gK56p2bdMP/UdPc5zlYOlXnMm642yytzfoK1X1R1Wm8qtzeyt1lhNddpqUebbkpDTrd1va4uJueT8/v7@7Orql6dzYrl5DzbTLPV5Hw9Ob8rynm6OnWX@9uH01VRn37LSnZKp/M5KZWcMiZPWaQ5hrAloCvQqVkJpuYu79tPe/aLXfvrcjNgPr2Q@WQsJ258kPvmiz3z@ePMFy9kfmzQEylj/kD05Z754ePMly9kvginpjCaGgrcNz9@NvjjF7KfG/BzDSFNzPv2q2fbr14q/gb9ghn7ad/@5Nn2Jy8Vf4N8HhsnxJ79dpV7lv1W80Xib0037MP32ceuOM9hH6v4EuZH0rCPXQDCffOjPfPpceZHL7V0WeKxPuyjP9pfeuXjzH@plZcMeZJZAOQ@@UT0XPNfYuU1NZC1xXs1wrp3HqJ7mcG7txRh9/qBde8VWPfCgHVvAli3xc@7vXvqNuVlt9sutQnDB1FxetU7juo20LFP@T2oH9aZPfs3Dv5IF5usPUjqnSpt2n3MA9JjsXuqtGn3M4c1kv6Z0qbd0xyU7p1cI9Yy5UHpnjW22bR7n8MaYf88adPueA5L90@Htpl3ULpvTdRaQ4ei2Tsm5t4i2d3RYen@ydC2Bjwo3beGWmviQ0hwR0d7J0m1Rjqf29NN6WJqjjDpnu@TAEejp/lqvamnZqxJcDEJ6uxrPQnGk2Cz1qLZ1KWnvmZ/5Nn91L5dtJIMYtVWxvZNr4tyirG1GGu8bUrsUw0a3rdbdI4eulE4aOofO23a3a0D8rtH7Jp2x2tQPh7vHjpt2j2xA/Ji54Bd0@6TDcqr3viqHT8SB@V3T5w27Q7aoHwyZjun65p2j@2AvNg5XNe0O22D8u6Aae@8adPuxh3SELvH8Zp2H25YI@xrhK8FzOTArA6Cme2cTm3a3ZYngD8@GErvNOreAdWm3Z/5E01iQ4dUm3Yv5ykJxOXTEkiGT0ugiJ6WQJI/LYF48rQEkvKJCZQ8LR3@v@AeqkmW2TxPP6SLxVVq6qUR6rHJhjH@s/kf/Yr/veLMfoMCzX6s3E9y0Erv0q/4ZAfHx2Bg7hs9bVY@XN7nWvuyLrWbNw/GBu3jOlvNgz@toX4zTl7m3zKvmKq2PebG3Odze@ZHl223WX5zWwcXETPFoRX7eKtLVyPW9iVazqmEIRsMV3Vb3H8sikWdr/WE4Wh0cnLyZmlGMz9Tys6qLC1nt@/Kk96vjibVT@/Ofmren4xH@E3T@zf59ciqXdg57iqtbjTOFkU6r97ZrjN7cOld@P69lVlrxfrdXfXZ/wXTl/c/fvwP):

```py
import re,json
string = r'''"Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer": {
                "jsonConfig": {"attributes":{"203":{"id":"203","code":"sizefootwear_conf","label":"EU","options":[{"id":"6320","label":"38","products":["69813"]},{"id":"6351","label":"38,5","products":["69817"]},{"id":"6335","label":"39","products":["69818"]},{"id":"6354","label":"40","products":["69819"]},{"id":"6338","label":"40,5","products":["69820"]},{"id":"6357","label":"41","products":["69821"]},{"id":"6326","label":"42","products":["69822"]},{"id":"6362","label":"42,5","products":["69823"]},{"id":"6341","label":"43","products":["69824"]},{"id":"6365","label":"44","products":["69814"]},{"id":"6344","label":"44,5","products":["69815"]},{"id":"6370","label":"45,5","products":["69816"]}],"position":"0"},"205":{"id":"205","code":"sizefootwearus_conf","label":"US","options":[{"id":"6319","label":"5,5","products":["69813"]},{"id":"6372","label":"6,0","products":["69817"]},{"id":"6334","label":"6,5","products":["69818"]},{"id":"6350","label":"7,0","products":["69819"]},{"id":"6337","label":"7,5","products":["69820"]},{"id":"6353","label":"8,0","products":["69821"]},{"id":"6325","label":"8,5","products":["69822"]},{"id":"6356","label":"9,0","products":["69823"]},{"id":"6340","label":"9,5","products":["69824"]},{"id":"6364","label":"10,0","products":["69814"]},{"id":"6343","label":"10,5","products":["69815"]},{"id":"6328","label":"11,5","products":["69816"]}],"position":"1"},"204":{"id":"204","code":"sizefootwearuk_conf","label":"UK","options":[{"id":"6318","label":"5,0","products":["69813"]},{"id":"6352","label":"5,5","products":["69817"]},{"id":"6743","label":"6,0-EU39","products":["69818"]},{"id":"6744","label":"6,0-EU40","products":["69819"]},{"id":"6355","label":"6,5","products":["69820"]},{"id":"6336","label":"7,0","products":["69821"]},{"id":"6361","label":"7,5","products":["69822"]},{"id":"6324","label":"8,0","products":["69823"]},{"id":"6363","label":"8,5","products":["69824"]},{"id":"6339","label":"9,0","products":["69814"]},{"id":"6366","label":"9,5","products":["69815"]},{"id":"6369","label":"10,5","products":["69816"]}],"position":"2"}},"template":"\u20ac<%- data.price %>","currencyFormat":"\u20ac%s","optionPrices":{"69813":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69814":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69815":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69816":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69817":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69818":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69819":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69820":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69821":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69822":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69823":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}},"69824":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":null}}},"priceFormat":{"pattern":"\u20ac%s","precision":2,"requiredPrecision":2,"decimalSymbol":".","groupSymbol":",","groupLength":3,"integerRequired":false},"prices":{"oldPrice":{"amount":139.99},"basePrice":{"amount":117.63865446218},"finalPrice":{"amount":139.99}},"productId":"69825","chooseText":"Choose an Option...","images":[],"index":{"69813":{"203":"6320","205":"6319","204":"6318"},"69814":{"203":"6365","205":"6364","204":"6339"},"69815":{"203":"6344","205":"6343","204":"6366"},"69816":{"203":"6370","205":"6328","204":"6369"},"69817":{"203":"6351","205":"6372","204":"6352"},"69818":{"203":"6335","205":"6334","204":"6743"},"69819":{"203":"6354","205":"6350","204":"6744"},"69820":{"203":"6338","205":"6337","204":"6355"},"69821":{"203":"6357","205":"6353","204":"6336"},"69822":{"203":"6326","205":"6325","204":"6361"},"69823":{"203":"6362","205":"6356","204":"6324"},"69824":{"203":"6341","205":"6340","204":"6363"}},"productStockAlert":{"entity":"69825","map":{"203":{"label":"52,5","":"","6610":"6610","6498":"6498","6582":"6582","6516":"6516","6501":"6501","6518":"6518","6504":"6504","6395":"6395","6404":"6404","6533":"6533","6407":"6407","6530":"6530","6410":"6410","6413":"6413","6416":"6416","6534":"6534","6419":"6419","6422":"6422","6425":"6425","6398":"6398","6401":"6401","6531":"6531","6431":"6431","6443":"6443","6446":"6446","6495":"6495","6449":"6449","6452":"6452","6455":"6455","6458":"6458","6461":"6461","6807":"6807","6464":"6464","6434":"6434","6437":"6437","6558":"6558","6440":"6440","6480":"6480","6481":"6481","6382":"6382","6465":"6465","6631":"6631","6332":"6332","6466":"6466","6348":"6348","6634":"6634","6320":"6320","6351":"6351","6384":"6384","6659":"6659","6335":"6335","6388":"6388","6508":"6508","6354":"6354","6338":"6338","6389":"6389","6664":"6664","6357":"6357","6390":"6390","6506":"6506","6637":"6637","6326":"6326","6362":"6362","6391":"6391","6640":"6640","6341":"6341","6392":"6392","6560":"6560","6365":"6365","6344":"6344","6385":"6385","6838":"6838","6368":"6368","6386":"6386","6370":"6370","6643":"6643","6628":"6628","6329":"6329","6529":"6529","6387":"6387","6843":"6843","6347":"6347","6470":"6470","6360":"6360","6646":"6646","6472":"6472","6323":"6323","6564":"6564","6593":"6593","6474":"6474","6376":"6376","6565":"6565","6561":"6561","6567":"6567","6604":"6604","6607":"6607"},"205":{"label":"18,0","":"","6513":"6513","6497":"6497","6583":"6583","6500":"6500","6821":"6821","6503":"6503","6532":"6532","6394":"6394","6403":"6403","6406":"6406","6409":"6409","6412":"6412","6415":"6415","6418":"6418","6421":"6421","6424":"6424","6397":"6397","6400":"6400","6430":"6430","6442":"6442","6445":"6445","6448":"6448","6451":"6451","6454":"6454","6457":"6457","6460":"6460","6463":"6463","6433":"6433","6436":"6436","6439":"6439","6555":"6555","6468":"6468","6507":"6507","6632":"6632","6331":"6331","6319":"6319","6635":"6635","6372":"6372","6334":"6334","6661":"6661","6350":"6350","6337":"6337","6663":"6663","6353":"6353","6619":"6619","6325":"6325","6621":"6621","6638":"6638","6356":"6356","6340":"6340","6623":"6623","6641":"6641","6364":"6364","6343":"6343","6625":"6625","6840":"6840","6367":"6367","6328":"6328","6644":"6644","6371":"6371","6346":"6346","6842":"6842","6359":"6359","6322":"6322","6647":"6647","6373":"6373","6566":"6566","6375":"6375","6562":"6562","6605":"6605","6608":"6608"},"204":{"label":"17,0","":"","6611":"6611","6514":"6514","6496":"6496","6515":"6515","6499":"6499","6517":"6517","6502":"6502","6393":"6393","6505":"6505","6402":"6402","6405":"6405","6408":"6408","6411":"6411","6414":"6414","6417":"6417","6420":"6420","6423":"6423","6396":"6396","6399":"6399","6429":"6429","6745":"6745","6441":"6441","6444":"6444","6447":"6447","6450":"6450","6453":"6453","6456":"6456","6459":"6459","6462":"6462","6432":"6432","6435":"6435","6438":"6438","6467":"6467","6381":"6381","6633":"6633","6330":"6330","6349":"6349","6636":"6636","6318":"6318","6352":"6352","6660":"6660","6333":"6333","6743":"6743","6744":"6744","6355":"6355","6662":"6662","6336":"6336","6620":"6620","6361":"6361","6622":"6622","6639":"6639","6324":"6324","6363":"6363","6624":"6624","6642":"6642","6339":"6339","6366":"6366","6626":"6626","6839":"6839","6342":"6342","6627":"6627","6369":"6369","6645":"6645","6327":"6327","6358":"6358","6841":"6841","6345":"6345","6471":"6471","6648":"6648","6321":"6321","6473":"6473","6374":"6374","6563":"6563","6606":"6606","6609":"6609"}},"child":{"6320_6319_6318_":{"entity":"69813","stock_number":0,"stock_status":false,"productId":"69813","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6365_6364_6339_":{"entity":"69814","stock_number":5,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69814","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6344_6343_6366_":{"entity":"69815","stock_number":3,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69815","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6370_6328_6369_":{"entity":"69816","stock_number":1,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69816","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6351_6372_6352_":{"entity":"69817","stock_number":0,"stock_status":false,"productId":"69817","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6335_6334_6743_":{"entity":"69818","stock_number":0,"stock_status":false,"productId":"69818","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6354_6350_6744_":{"entity":"69819","stock_number":0,"stock_status":false,"productId":"69819","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6338_6337_6355_":{"entity":"69820","stock_number":0,"stock_status":false,"productId":"69820","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6357_6353_6336_":{"entity":"69821","stock_number":3,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69821","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6326_6325_6361_":{"entity":"69822","stock_number":4,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69822","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6362_6356_6324_":{"entity":"69823","stock_number":6,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69823","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"},"6341_6340_6363_":{"entity":"69824","stock_number":6,"stock_status":true,"productId":"69824","parent_url":"https:\/\/www.bstn.com\/eu_en\/p\/jordan-jordan-why-not-zer0-4-dd4889-006-0250549"}}},"stock":{"69813":0,"69814":5,"69815":3,"69816":1,"69817":0,"69818":0,"69819":0,"69820":0,"69821":3,"69822":4,"69823":6,"69824":6}},
                "jsonSwatchConfig": {"203":{"6320":{"type":"0","value":"38","label":"38"},"6351":{"type":"0","value":"38,5","label":"38,5"},"6335":{"type":"0","value":"39","label":"39"},"6354":{"type":"0","value":"40","label":"40"},"6338":{"type":"0","value":"40,5","label":"40,5"},"6357":{"type":"0","value":"41","label":"41"},"6326":{"type":"0","value":"42","label":"42"},"6362":{"type":"0","value":"42,5","label":"42,5"},"6341":{"type":"0","value":"43","label":"43"},"6365":{"type":"0","value":"44","label":"44"},"6344":{"type":"0","value":"44,5","label":"44,5"},"6370":{"type":"0","value":"45,5","label":"45,5"},"additional_data":"{\"swatch_input_type\":\"text\",\"update_product_preview_image\":\"0\",\"use_product_image_for_swatch\":0}"},"205":{"6319":{"type":"0","value":"5,5","label":"5,5"},"6372":{"type":"0","value":"6,0","label":"6,0"},"6334":{"type":"0","value":"6,5","label":"6,5"},"6350":{"type":"0","value":"7,0","label":"7,0"},"6337":{"type":"0","value":"7,5","label":"7,5"},"6353":{"type":"0","value":"8,0","label":"8,0"},"6325":{"type":"0","value":"8,5","label":"8,5"},"6356":{"type":"0","value":"9,0","label":"9,0"},"6340":{"type":"0","value":"9,5","label":"9,5"},"6364":{"type":"0","value":"10,0","label":"10,0"},"6343":{"type":"0","value":"10,5","label":"10,5"},"6328":{"type":"0","value":"11,5","label":"11,5"},"additional_data":"{\"swatch_input_type\":\"text\",\"update_product_preview_image\":\"0\",\"use_product_image_for_swatch\":0}"},"204":{"6318":{"type":"0","value":"5,0","label":"5,0"},"6352":{"type":"0","value":"5,5","label":"5,5"},"6743":{"type":"0","value":"6,0-EU39","label":"6,0-EU39"},"6744":{"type":"0","value":"6,0-EU40","label":"6,0-EU40"},"6355":{"type":"0","value":"6,5","label":"6,5"},"6336":{"type":"0","value":"7,0","label":"7,0"},"6361":{"type":"0","value":"7,5","label":"7,5"},"6324":{"type":"0","value":"8,0","label":"8,0"},"6363":{"type":"0","value":"8,5","label":"8,5"},"6339":{"type":"0","value":"9,0","label":"9,0"},"6366":{"type":"0","value":"9,5","label":"9,5"},"6369":{"type":"0","value":"10,5","label":"10,5"},"additional_data":"{\"swatch_input_type\":\"text\",\"update_product_preview_image\":\"0\",\"use_product_image_for_swatch\":0}"}},
                "mediaCallback": "https\u003A\u002F\u002Fwww.bstn.com\u002Feu_en\u002Fswatches\u002Fajax\u002Fmedia\u002F",
                "gallerySwitchStrategy": "prepend",
                "jsonSwatchImageSizeConfig": {"swatchImage":{"width":30,"height":20},"swatchThumb":{"height":90,"width":110}},
                "showTooltip": 1  '''
match = re.search(r'"jsonConfig":\s*(.*})', string)
if match:
    js = json.loads(match.group(1))
    print(js["attributes"])
```

Comment: Will this work if `jsonConfig` spans into multiple lines?

Comment: @PEdroArthur, should work if the `re.DOTALL` flag is added to `re.search()`

Comment: The example string has `jsonConfig` on one line. I do not guarantee it will still work with several line json code.

Comment: By testing this example it works exactly how I wanted :) I would like to have a explanation if its ok what `(.*})'` part does?

Comment: @MichaelRuth it was just a example of how this approach can fail. Another example is if `jsonConfig` and `jsonSwatchConfig` are in the same line. My bottom line is that there is no simple, standard regex that can correctly parse this structure.

Comment: @PEdroArthur That is all true. Here, the extraction is possible only because the json is on one line.

Comment: @PEdroArthur, I totally agree. The correct way to do this is to use a JSON parser.

Comment: @MichaelRuth I agree, too. And I am using it in my answer. The problem OP has is isolating the JSON from some non-JSON text. Then, a regex is handy.