# How to use regex groups to split key & values

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have some data I would like to extract to build an object in JS but I can't find how to do with regex.

On regex101 the regex below seems to fit but it doesn't in my code...

Here is the type of data:

```
"TEST_firstname:john_lastname:doe_age:45"
```

And I would want to extract key and values (key is between `"_"` and `":"`, value is between `":"` and `"_"`

I tried with this : `(?<key>(?<=\_)(.*?)(?=\:))|(?<value>(?<=\:)(.*?)((?=\_)|$))`

Could someone help me to find the good regex?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: IF you replace _ with comma, then it is standard json, so you can easy to use validation in this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```js
/([^_:]+):([^_]+)/g
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/rJuWx2/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^_:]+                   any character except: '_', ':' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^_]+                    any character except: '_' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

**JavaScript code**:

```js
const regex = /([^_:]+):([^_]+)/g;
const str = `TEST_firstname:john_lastname:doe_age:45`;
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log(`${m[1]} >>> ${m[2]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.prototype.matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) and [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce it to an Object of key:value pairs

```js
const s = "TEST_firstname:john_lastname:doe_age:45";
const m = s.matchAll(/([^:_]+):([^_]+)/g);
const user = [...m].reduce((ob, [m,k,v]) => (ob[k] = v, ob), {});

console.log(user);
```