# How to find unpredictable parent of specific child in JSON using regexp?

Tags: json, regex

In the following JSON, how can I use a regular expression to match the parent key named "`Item of Equipment`", whose value is changing and unpredictable?

`"type": "title"` Is unique to this node, as is presence of `"title:"`.

AKA: "How can I match a parent value by using a child?

An alternative to find "`Item of Equipment`" is to look for it in the property "`name`", where it is duplicated, as a sibling of `"type": "title`". It's the case that `"type": "title"` always uniquely has a sibling of "`name`"

```
    ..
    "id": "Xkt@",
    "name": "My Email",
    "type": "email"
  },
  "Item of Equipment": {
    "id": "title",
    "title": {},
    "name": "Item of Equipment",
    "type": "title"
  },
  "My Date": {
    "id": "nYcK",
    "name": "My Date",
    "type": "date",
    ..
```

I won't use a JSON parser, I won't have access. I am running this through the "Match" action of iOS Shortcuts.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Answer (score 0):

### Notes

1. Based on [JSON validation via RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845829/406712).
2. Addition of "Atomic Groups" to avoid backtracking.
3. Assumption that the iOS "Match" uses regular expressions (ICU) similar to Perl.
4. If a single line regular expression is required, that is left for an exercise for the reader.
5. Note performance / usability with large JSON input may cause regular expression engine to have issues ("your mileage may vary").

### RegEx

```
(?(DEFINE)
     (?<number>   (?>-? (?= [1-9]|0(?!\d) ) \d+ (\.\d+)? ([eE] [+-]? \d+)?) )
     (?<boolean>   (?> true | false | null ))
     (?<unquoted>  (?>  ([^"\\]* | \\ ["\\bfnrt\/] | \\ u [0-9a-f]{4} )* ))
     (?<string>    (?>" (?&unquoted) " ))
     (?<array>     (?> \[  (?:  (?&json)  (?: , (?&json)  )*  )?  \s* \] ))
     (?<pair>      (?> \s* (?&string) \s* : (?&json)  ))
     (?<object>    (?>\{  (?:  (?&pair)  (?: , (?&pair)  )*  )?  \s* \} ))
     (?<json>   (?>\s* (?: (?&number) | (?&boolean) | (?&string) | (?&array) | (?&object) ) \s* ))
  )
(?<=")           # Lookbehind for quote before parent key string
(?&unquoted)     # parent key string 
(?=              # Lookahead for object properties including unique property marker
"\s*:\s*{\s*
(?:  (?&pair)  (?: , (?&pair)  )*  )?    # any number of property key value pairs, optional.
(?:(?:\s* , )?\s* "type"\s*:\s*"title")  # unique property marker, optionally perfixed with comma.
(?: \s*, (?&pair)  )*                    # any number of property key value pairs, optional.
\s*}
)
```

### Proof

https://regex101.com/r/kN74Th/1