# Load into BigQuery - one column to handle arbitrary json field (empty array, dict with different fields, etc.)

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery, schema

We have the following three JSONs with data that should be loaded in the same table:

```
{ "name": "tom", "customValues": [] }
{ "name": "joe", "customValues": { "member": "1" } }
{ "name": "joe", "customValues": { "year": "2020", "number": "3" } }
```

We load data with the python `bigquery.LoadJobConfig` function:

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=SCHEMA_MAP.get(bq_table) if autodetect == False else None,
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
    write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE if remove_old == True else bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    autodetect=autodetect
)
```

`SCHEMA_MAP` is a dictionary of arrays, where each array in the schema for one of our tables. We define our BigQuery schema in python using the python `bigquery.SchemaField` function. If each of the 3 JSONs above were going into 3 different tables, I would have their table schemas defined as:

```
SCHEMA_T1 = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("customValues", "STRING", mode="REPEATED")
]

SCHEMA_T2 = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("customValues", "RECORD", mode="REPEATED", fields=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("member", "STRING")
    ])
]

SCHEMA_T3 = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("customValues", "RECORD", mode="REPEATED", fields=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("year", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("number", "STRING")
    ])
]
```

Is it possible to define the `customValues` column to handle all 3 of these different data types in one single table? How would the schema be defined for this? Currently, if `SCHEMA_T1` is used and data in the forms of T2 or T3 is uploaded, the upload fails and it returns an error `Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: JSON object specified for non-record field: customValues`. Similar errors for the other schemas. Is there a generic **any json** field in BigQuery that can be used for this?

Comment: Just to confirm, your `.json` file have all those different schemas on a single file? why not filter the records (like this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json)) first and then base each filtered file built your custom column and then perform the operation.

Comment: we have a strong preference to load data with no transformations. prefer to load raw data as is and then we have transform queries that do all the cleaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery now supports `JSON` as a data type (from January 2022, you are lucky on the timing!), [ref here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data#create_a_table_with_a_json_column)

Therefore you should be able to go with:

```
SCHEMA_T = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("customValues", "JSON")
]
```

Answer (score 2):

As `JSON` feature is still in `preview` for bigquery (see [launch stages](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages)). As a workaround, you can use `load_table_from_dataframe` from the bigquery client to load data from data columns that might require some refinement before pushing into our working table.

Let's see on your scenario, lets said we have a `data.json` file with raw data:

**data.json**

```
[
    {
        "name": "tom",
        "customValues": []
    },
    {
        "name": "joe",
        "customValues": {
            "member": "1"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "joe",
        "customValues": {
            "year": "2020",
            "number": "3"
        }
    }
]
```

And we have a single table on bigquery that we need to populate.

```
create or replace table "my-project.my-dataset.a-table" (
   name STRING,
   customValues STRING
)
```

**load.py**

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd

client = bigquery.Client()

table_id = "project-id.dataset-id.a-table"
df = pd.read_json('data.json')
df["customValues"]= df["customValues"].apply(str)

print(df.shape)
print(df.head())

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.PARQUET, autodetect=True)
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id, job_config=job_config)
job.result() 

table = client.get_table(table_id)  
print("Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id))
```

**output**

```
| **name** | **customValues**                |
|----------|---------------------------------|
| tom      | []                              |
| joe      | {'member': '1'}                 |
| joe      | {'year': '2020', 'number': '3'} |
```

As you can see, regardless of the structure of `customValues` we are able to have that inserted on our working table ( which only have 2 columns ). We load the json data into a dataframe and then we just update the datatype column to fit our column type by using `apply`. For more information about using `apply` please visit this [link](https://dataindependent.com/pandas/pandas-apply-pd-dataframe-apply/).