# Regex for GraphQL - is it possible?

Tags: regex, string, validation, graphql

In the same vein as [Regex to Validate JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json), for reasons of pure interest and novelty, I am looking for a regex to validate that a string containing a GraphQL-query is syntactically valid.

I know there are loads of libraries that will allow me to validate GraphQL in different languages, but I am specifically looking for a solution using Regular Expressions.

Have anyone cracked the case of a regular expression that can determine whether a string has valid GraphQL query syntax - as per the latest spec from [spec.graphql.org](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021)?

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. With the arbitrary nesting, GraphQL query syntax is not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) and cannot be matched with regular expressions.

Comment: Mm, yes, you are strictly speaking correct, although I think that recursive regex parsing is possible in quite a few languages - JSON is not a regular language either, but there [are ways to overcome the limitations when the regex parser allows recursive regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845829/2366976)

Comment: If you are working with a non-regular regex engine, please state so in the question. Also, if you take that JSON regex as a starting point, what are you stuck on trying this yourself?

Comment: @TobiasRoland that json regex validator doesn't seem safe to me: https://3v4l.org/DpiAd